# Python script unable to connect to MySQL db with no password

Tags: python, mysql

I am having a weird issue with my python script. My script has to connect to MySQL DB. This is the code:

```
try:
   conn = MySQLdb.connect( user='root', host = 'localhost')
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   databases = cursor.fetchall()
   cursor.close()
except Exception as e:
   print e
```

when I run this script I have and error like:

```
(1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO")
```

in the other hand, I can connect to MySQL just by entering `MySQL` (without password).

Why am I having this error with my python script when there is no password to root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the syntax. You should have the MySql connector for Python

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='database_name')
cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Provide empty password
try this

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect( user='root', host = 'localhost', passwd='')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (inside the bloc try except)

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',host='localhost',                          
                              database='your_database_name')
conn.close()
```