# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: python, mysql-connector, flask-login, access-denied, mysql-error-1045

I'm trying to connect database for my login page, using Xampp server (myphpadmin)

The python code as follows:

**run.py**

```
from application import app

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**init.py**

```
from flask import Flask 

app=Flask(__name__)

from application import main
```

**main.py**

```
from application import app
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import mysql.connector


@app.route('/')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/result',methods=['POST','GET'])
def result():
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database="user-system"
    )
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    if request.method=='POST':
        signup=request.form
        username=signup['user']
        password=signup['pass']
        mycursor.execute("select *form user where name=='"+username+"' and password=='"+password+"'")
        r=mycursor.fetchall()
        count=mycursor.rowcount
        if count==1:
            return render_template("test.html")
        elif count> 1:
            return "More than One USER "
        else:
            return render_template("login.html")
    mydb.commit()
    mycursor.close()
```

The code is running successfully but after login using the database data it redirects me  to the following error is :

[Image shows the Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2dXj.png)

Comment: the order should be "user, password, host", I think this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728426/python-script-unable-to-connect-to-mysql-db-with-no-password

Answer (score 0):

You're using user `root` with no password maybe not be allowed. My Suggest is to add new user account with a password to access your MySQL database correctly with this steps:

1. Open phpMyAdmin.
2. Click `User accounts`
3. Click `Add user account`
4. Put your new username and fill the password, then check all on `Global Privileges` and click Go
5. Finally, edit this lines:

```
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="<your new username>",
        password="<your new password>",
        database="user-system"
    )
```